# Probability to get 170 1's

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose we throw a fair die 1000 times. What is the probability we get 170 1's?

> The exact number is $P={1000\choose 170}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)^{170}\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{830}$.

We can approximate with normal distribution because we have independent events, a large and constant number of trials and an a-priori known probability with only two outcomes, success (get an 1) or failure (get anything else).

We have $μ = np = 1000 \cdot\frac{1}{6} = 166.66$ and
$σ = \sqrt npq = 11.785$.

$z = \frac{170 - 166.66}{11.785} = 0.2828$

Hence the probability is 0.6103.
Is it correct? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

First, let's label each distribution so as to make clear which distribution I am referring to.

Let $X$ be the original, *exact* Binomial distribution: $X\sim B\left(1000,\frac{1}{6}\right).$ Then you want $P(X=170),$ and the calculation you suggest, $P={1000\choose 170}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)^{170}\bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{830}$, is correct, and gives you the *exact* probability of $P(X=170).$

Let's call the normal approximation to this distribution $Y,$ which is valid since $np$ and $np(1-p)$ are both $>5$. You should always check this fact before continuing with a normal approximation to a Binomial distribution. $Y\sim N\left(\frac{1000}{6}, \frac{5000}{36}\right),$ or roughly, $(167,12)$, although we use the exact values in calculations of course.

$Z$ is the standardised normal distribution: $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and note that when transferring between $Y$ and $Z$, all you are really doing is *coding* the mean and standard deviation of the distributions $Y$ and $Z$.

You have calculated $P(Z< 0.2828) = 0.6103,$ which is the same as $P(Y< 170),$ or equally, $=P(Y\leq 170)$. But this is the area to the *left* of $170$ on the $Y$ distribution (under the graph), so represents approximately (is equal to) $P(X\leq 170) = P(X=170) + P(X=169) + P(X=168)+\ldots.$ But the question asks for $P(X=170)$, and for this, you should calculate, $P(169.5<Y<170.5),$ and the "$0.5$ adjustment" is known as a "continuity correction". Although I'm not why this is considered "an adjustment".

Comment: I got it, thank you. Very clear explanation, congrats.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help.

Comment: i think the term "adjustment" is more commonly used in the one-sided P(X<170) case, where we would compute P(Z<169.5) instead of P(Z<170) (or P(Z<170.5) if the desired binomial probability was instead P(X<=170)). Then, we can say that we "adjusted" the limit by 0.5. I agree it doesn't make much sense in the context of this question.

Answer (score 2):

No, the question is asking for P(X=170) and when you gave answer for normal approximation you found $P(X\leq 170)$. Use continuity correction, so when approximating to normal distribution calculate $P(170-0.5\leq X\leq 170+0.5)$.